# JEDIS/REDIS 'ON' Keyword or broken query?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

Very new to REDIS, and having issues using JSON/Index/Query that is driving me crazy.

Example struct

```
public class MyType implements Serializable {
{
    @SerializedName("myval")
    @Expose
    private Integer myval;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
}
```

I am easily using redis-stack, and pushing in this class using JSON/GSON.

Problem comes when I try to query.

I have an index set up that looks like

```
 Schema testSchema = new Schema().addTextField("$.status",1.0);
 myJedis.ftCreate("STATUSINDEX",IndexOperations().setDefault(rule),testSchema);
```

I then insert a few json blobs, some with status="on", and others with status="OFF"

Using redisInsight/Browser, I can see my json, with status ON and OFF as set in previous.

Using redisInsight/RediSearch:
If I search using
FT.SEARCH "STATUSINDEX" '@&.status:OFF'
I get the json objects with status 'OFF' as expected.

If I search using
FT.SEARCH "STATUSINDEX" '@&.status:ON'
I get nothing.

If I repeat the test, but substitute "MYON" instead of "ON" when inserting the objects, then the search:
FT.SEARCH "STATUSINDEX" '@&.status:MYON'
returns the expected json objects.

I must be doing something wrong, or the value 'on' is reserved??

TIA, Wayne

Tried many different tests and combinations of status types.  Only seems to happen using "ON"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the reason is that you've defined the 'status' field as text in the index's schema. The text type is used for free-text searches, and as such has the notion of "stop words" - common words that are ignored - and "on" is probably there.

You should use a tag field instead.